# Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:/Users/Roger/Desktop/MiniJuego1.py", line 67

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

sigo intentando hacer un minijuego, le he añadido un pequeño menú pero ahora no funciona,
cuando ejecuto sale lo normal de
`1 Para juego, 2 para tests`
Cuando pongo 2 para la zona de tests te lleva ahí:

```
Bienvenido a la zona de tests
Qué desea hacer?
1. Volver al juego
2. Nada
Escoja una opción
```

Pongo el 1 para volver al juego, pero aparece el error

```
  File "c:/Users/Roger/Desktop/MiniJuego1.py", line 67, in <module>
    menuTests()
  File "c:/Users/Roger/Desktop/MiniJuego1.py", line 24, in menuTests
    gamemini()
NameError: name 'gamemini' is not defined
```

El código es:

```
import os, sys

def cleaning():
    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        os.system('cls')
    elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
        os.system('clear')
    elif sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
        os.system('clear')
#Before
n = int(0)
#Variables
life = int(5)
#Modules
import random
#Functions
def menuTests():
    print("Bienvenido a la zona de tests")
    print("Qué desea hacer?")
    print("1. Volver al juego")
    print("2. Nada")
    sel = float(input("Escoja una opción: "))
    if float(sel == 1):
        gamemini()       
def rnd():
    n = random.randint(0,1)
def gameMini():
    global life
    if life <= 0:
        print("Perdiste..... pulsa ENTER para salir")
        input("")
        exit()
    cleaning()
    print("Use WASD to move, then ENTER to do the action")
    print("Y = You")
    print("  W")
    print("A Y D")
    print("  S")
    print("Move now with WASD")
    loca = str(input(""))
    cleaning()
    if loca == "w":
        n = random.randint(0,1)
    if loca == "a":
        n = random.randint(0,1)
    if loca == "s":
        n = random.randint(0,1)
    if loca == "d":
        n = random.randint(0,1)
    if int(n == 1):
        life = life - 1
        print(life)
        print("Perdiste una vida, pulsa ENTER para continuar")
        input("")
        gameMini()
    if int(n == 0):
        life = life - 0
        print(life)
        print("No perdiste nada, pulsa ENTER para continuar")
        input("")
        gameMini()
#Code
mode = float(input("1 Para juego, 2 para tests: "))
if float(mode == 1):
     gameMini()
elif float(mode == 2):
    menuTests()
```

Comment: el error es bastante claro `NameError: name 'gamemini' is not defined` tu funcion esta en mayuscula y la llamas en minuscula ... `gamemini()` y la funcion se llama `gameMini()`

Comment: Gracias, ya funciona :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente fijate que cuando llamas a la función:

```
def menuTests():
print("Bienvenido a la zona de tests")
print("Qué desea hacer?")
print("1. Volver al juego")
print("2. Nada")
sel = float(input("Escoja una opción: "))
if float(sel == 1):
    gamemini()
```

La llamas distinto a como se llama realmente. Fíjate que en la definición de la función la pusiste como game**M**ini con **m mayúsculas!** Es solo eso, o bien cambia el llamado de la función o bien cambia el nombre de la función.
Por si no te quedó claro te pongo como lo resolví yo(solo cambie el llamado de la funcion xD):

```
import os, sys

def cleaning():
    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        os.system('cls')
    elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
        os.system('clear')
    elif sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
        os.system('clear')
#Before
n = int(0)
#Variables
life = int(5)
#Modules
import random
#Functions
def menuTests():
    print("Bienvenido a la zona de tests")
    print("Qué desea hacer?")
    print("1. Volver al juego")
    print("2. Nada")
    sel = float(input("Escoja una opción: "))
    if float(sel == 1):
        gameMini()       
def rnd():
    n = random.randint(0,1)
def gameMini():
    global life
    if life <= 0:
        print("Perdiste..... pulsa ENTER para salir")
        input("")
        exit()
    cleaning()
    print("Use WASD to move, then ENTER to do the action")
    print("Y = You")
    print("  W")
    print("A Y D")
    print("  S")
    print("Move now with WASD")
    loca = str(input(""))
    cleaning()
    if loca == "w":
        n = random.randint(0,1)
    if loca == "a":
        n = random.randint(0,1)
    if loca == "s":
        n = random.randint(0,1)
    if loca == "d":
        n = random.randint(0,1)
    if int(n == 1):
        life = life - 1
        print(life)
        print("Perdiste una vida, pulsa ENTER para continuar")
        input("")
        gameMini()
    if int(n == 0):
        life = life - 0
        print(life)
        print("No perdiste nada, pulsa ENTER para continuar")
        input("")
        gameMini()
#Code
mode = float(input("1 Para juego, 2 para tests: "))
if float(mode == 1):
     gameMini()
elif float(mode == 2):
    menuTests()
```

Espero haberte ayudado!